# Source control in ADX

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-data-explorer, adx

I have an ADX cluster deployed in azure . I want to integrate it with  azure devops git repository so that all the database ,schema changes get pushed to the central repository that could be released to other environments

Is there any way to achieve this?

Tried doing it through azure data explorer pipeline tools but that didn’t work

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this article:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/automated-deploy-overview.

It goes through the different approaches and tools to deploy infra / schema entities / data.  There is an example with Azure DevOps at the end.